# Extending the ApplicationUser in Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, code-first, asp.net-identity-2

So I am trying to extend the ApplicationUser class by adding the following columns..

- CreateUserId
- CreateDate
- UpdateUserId
- UpdateDate

Here is my code I added to the ApplicationCode class

```
[MaxLength(128)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Create User Id is Required.")]
public string CreateUserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CreateUserId")]
public ApplicationUser CreateUser { get; set; }

public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

[MaxLength(128)]
public string UpdateUserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("UpdateUserId")]
public ApplicationUser UpdateUser { get; set; }

public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
```

What I am ultimately trying to do is have the `CreateUserId` have a foreign key constraint to point back to `ApplicationUser.Id` (Required), and have `UpdateUserId` have a foreign key constraint to point back to `ApplicationUser.Id` (Optional)

I am getting the following error though:

> ApplicationUser_UpdateUser_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role     'ApplicationUser_UpdateUser_Target' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_UpdateUser'. Because the      Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Can anyone give me some direction on setting this up?

Edit..

I think I figured it out

```
public string UpdateUserId { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser UpdateUser { get; set; }

public string CreateUserId { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser CreateUser { get; set; }

public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.CreateUser)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.CreateUserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.UpdateUser)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.UpdateUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Not adding this as an answer because I'm not 100% positive, but I think that if you have multiple navigation properties that point to the same entity then you need to configure it using the Fluent API. I'm not sure you can do it using Data Annotations.

Comment: I tried adding

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(a => a.CreateUser);

Comment: Please do not add code examples as comments.  Please update the answer with additional code.  Questions should be able to stand by themselves, and adding code as comments requires more reading to answer the question.